# Google Foobar Challenge(Python) - Lucky LAMBS problem

Tags: python

**The Question is:**

Being a henchman isn't all drudgery. Occasionally, when Commander Lambda is feeling generous, she'll hand out Lucky LAMBs (Lambda's All-purpose Money Bucks). Henchmen can use Lucky LAMBs to buy things like a second pair of socks, a pillow for their bunks, or even a third daily meal!

However, actually passing out LAMBs isn't easy. Each henchman squad has a strict seniority ranking which must be respected - or else the henchmen will revolt and you'll all get demoted back to minions again!

There are 4 key rules which you must follow in order to avoid a revolt:

1. The most junior henchman (with the least seniority) gets exactly 1 LAMB.  (There will always be at
   least 1 henchman on a team.)
2. A henchman will revolt if the person who ranks immediately above them gets more than double the
   number of LAMBs they do.
3. A henchman will revolt if the amount of LAMBs given to their next two subordinates combined is
   more than the number of LAMBs they get.  (Note that the two most junior henchmen won't have two
   subordinates, so this rule doesn't apply to them.  The 2nd most junior henchman would require at
   least as many LAMBs as the most junior henchman.)
4. You can always find more henchmen to pay - the Commander has plenty of employees.  If there are
   enough LAMBs left over such that another henchman could be added as the most senior while obeying
   the other rules, you must always add and pay that henchman.

Note that you may not be able to hand out all the LAMBs. A single LAMB cannot be subdivided. That is, all henchmen must get a positive integer number of LAMBs.

Write a function called solution(total_lambs), where total_lambs is the integer number of LAMBs in the handout you are trying to divide. It should return an integer which represents the difference between the minimum and maximum number of henchmen who can share the LAMBs (that is, being as generous as possible to those you pay and as stingy as possible, respectively) while still obeying all of the above rules to avoid a revolt.  For instance, if you had 10 LAMBs and were as generous as possible, you could only pay 3 henchmen (1, 2, and 4 LAMBs, in order of ascending seniority), whereas if you were as stingy as possible, you could pay 4 henchmen (1, 1, 2, and 3 LAMBs). Therefore, solution(10) should return 4-3 = 1.

To keep things interesting, Commander Lambda varies the sizes of the Lucky LAMB payouts. You can expect total_lambs to always be a positive integer less than 1 billion (10 ^ 9).

**My Code:**

```
def solution(total_lambs):
if total_lambs <= 10**9:
    return h_stin(total_lambs) - h_gen(total_lambs)
else: return 0

def h_gen(total_lambs):
x = 1
# I have directly used formulas for sum and nth term of GP instead of assigning them variables
while (2**x - 1) < total_lambs:
    x += 1
if (2**x - 1) <= total_lambs or 2**(x-2) + 2**(x-3) <= total_lambs - (2**(x-1) - 1):
    return x
else: return x-1

def h_stin(total_lambs):
if total_lambs == 1:
    return 1
if total_lambs == 2:
    return 2
arr = [1, 1]
for i in range(1,10**9):
    if sum(arr) < total_lambs:
        arr.append(arr[i] + arr[i-1])
    else: break
if sum(arr) <= total_lambs:
    return len(arr)
else: return len(arr) - 1
```

When I run this code in command line on my pc it returns the correct output but when I verify it on the foobar terminal it say Test Failed for 9 of the 10 cases. Can someone help me with this?
Also if my code is wrong please tell me about it too. Thanks!!

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753294/lovely-lucky-lambs-last-test-case-not-passing#:~:text=Being%20a%20henchman%20isn't,even%20a%20third%20daily%20meal!

Comment: Thank u, but I found the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you're generous, you pay out 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 so that n henchman get `2**n - 1` units.

When you're stingy, you pay out 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ... (can you say Fibonacci?), so that m henchmen get the sum of F(0), ..... F(m - 1) which is F(m + 1) - 1.

So you have to find the largest n such that `2 ** n - 1 <= lambs` and the largest m such that `F(m + 1) - 1 <= lambs`.

This is a Google coding challenge, so you need to write the code yourself.